# (get-date).today fails retrieve the date info

Tags: powershell

I retrieve the static property of (get-date)

```
 ~ λ (get-date) | get-member -static | select -last 3

   TypeName: System.DateTime

Name   MemberType Definition
----   ---------- ----------
Now    Property   datetime Now {get;}
Today  Property   datetime Today {get;}
UtcNow Property   datetime UtcNow {get;}
```

Then tried :

```
(get-date).today
```

it report nothing, but `[datetime]` works:

```
 ~ λ [datetime]::today

September 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

What's the problem with my usage of (get-date)?

Comment: *Static properties and methods are defined on the class of objects, not on any particular instance of the class.*

Comment: To add to @AbdulNiyasPM’s comment, here’s a link to the (brief) documentation for the “Static member operator ::” for reference… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#static-member-operator-

Comment: If you want to know what is available to a PS command you're better off piping it to `Get-Member` e.g. `Get-Date | Get-Member`. In your case,m you could have used `(Get-Date).DateTime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You're using the wrong operator!

Instance members (methods and properties that are tied to *instances* of a type) are accessed with the instance member invocation operator `.`:

```
<instanceReference>.<memberName>
```

For example, let's say we wanted to get the hour of the day from a specific `[datetime]` value:

```
# This will store a [datetime] instance in $date
$date = Get-Date

# To access the `Hour` value of said instance, use `.`:
$date.Hour
```

*Static* members (methods and properties that are tied to a type but are *global*) are accessed with the *static* member invocation operator `::`:

```
<instanceOrTypeReference>::<memberName>
```

For example, to access the static `Today` field, use either a `[datetime]` type literal or an instance in conjunction with `::`:

```
[datetime]::Today
# or
(Get-Date)::Today
```